# I want the floating left div's to adjust width on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Can any one tell why the `<div>` width is NOT adjusted to `48%` as the screen size changes? Is it because I have used `position: relative;`?

CSS:

```
.wrap {
  width: 24%;
  background: white;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

@media(max-width: 580px){
  width: 48%;
}
```

Comment: To help you with your CSS we first need to see your ["Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) HTML and attempted CSS, so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: And in the meanwhile `@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {  .wrap { width: 48%; } }`

Comment: In your media-query you never stated **which element** should have `width:48%` applied. You missed the `.wrap` selector there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you just forgot the `.wrap` and curly braces in the media query:

```
@media(max-width: 580px) {
  .wrap {
    width:48%;
  }
}
```

Also see [these examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) about how to notate media queries.

Comment: I have done that... still it is not solved... See this script background:yellow; width:58%; In this the background becomes yellow but not the width... So what is the problem for width?

Comment: Please update your question then with the whole problematic code.

Answer (score 2):

Solution to your problem

```
@media(max-width: 580px){
  .wrap{
  width:48%;
  }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/11opj4nq/

Comment: I have done that... still it is not solved... See this script   `background:yellow;

width:58%;`                                    In this the background becomes yellow but not the width... So what is the problem for width?

Answer (score 1):

Hi remember about mobile first :) . Good practice is to override code in larger devices.

```
.wrap {
 width: 48%;
 background: white;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 580px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 24%;
    margin: 15px; 
  }
}
```